# How to count entries of two consecutive rows and keep only second row in a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have such a dataframe:

```
DATE |  VALUE
23/07/21 01 | 20
23/07/21 02 | 10
23/07/21 03 | 15
23/07/21 04 | 200
```

What I want to get is new dataframe which sums up the entries of two consecutive rows of column `VALUE` and keeps the entry of the second row for column `DATE`.

It should look like this one:

```
DATE |  VALUE
23/07/21 02 |   30
23/07/21 04 |   215
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is "DATE" a column or the DataFrame index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).agg({'DATE':'last', 'VALUE':'sum'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `rolling`:

```
>>> df.set_index("DATE").rolling(2).sum().iloc[1::2].reset_index()

            DATE  VALUE
0  2021-07-21 02   30.0
1  2021-07-21 04  115.0
```

This becomes considerably faster with a larger DataFrame:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

>>> %timeit df.set_index("DATE").rolling(2).sum().iloc[1::2].reset_index()
1.33 ms ± 15.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).agg({'DATE':'last', 'VALUE':'sum'})
2.15 ms ± 108 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```